# How to manage nested pages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a project that uses lots of pages, can you give me ideas how to manage it easily.
Do you use a plugin? There are only few tutorials about Wordpress as CMS,  so Im just curious and dont know if I can pull this off.

Thanks, any help will do.

Answer (score 0):

Define "a lot of pages." I have projects with 25-100 pages (and well over 1,000 posts) that use WordPress as a CMS. I generally use the standard page management tools from the /wp-admin administrative area. I generally find pages with the search function, as opposed to the sequential list.

The most useful edit mechanism I've found is making sure the page templates have an "edit this page" link, so that logged-in-users with appropriate authority can edit a page with just a click, rather than having to go through the administrative area first.

Comment: What I mean about 'lots of pages' is I have nested pages that I want to limit the the children that is showing. Its like a page in page then another page , its hard to explain (its like a product catalogue) ,...anyway.. what plugins do you use for a CMS wordpress?can you recommend also too. thanks man for the help

Answer (score 0):

there used to be a plugin that would 'hide' child pages, this stopped working with WordPress 2.7 i believe. however a quick Google search returns this:

`http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-collapse-subpages/`